# How do I get the current Time Zone offset without the daylight saving in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, timezone-offset

My browser is in Chicago.
When using 
`(new Date()).getTimezoneOffset()/60` I get 5 hours because we are now in Daylight Saving.

I need a statement to return 6 because Chicago is in "(GMT-06:00) Central Time"

I need to get the offset for all USA time zones users regardless of Daylight saving. 
I need to show my users a dropdown of USA time zones if they want the results of their request to be delivered in a different time zone. the default should be the current. I will use the delta.
How do I get the current Time Zone offset without the daylight saving in JavaScript?

I am using React if it matters. Also "date-fns" but did not see a way to get it.

Thank you.

Comment: You can check `gettimezoneoffset`

Comment: "gettimezoneoffset" is influenced by Daylight saving. I need to show my users a dropdown of USA time zones if they want the results of their request to be delivered in a different time zone. the default should be the current. I will use the delta.

Answer (score 1):

If all you care about is the offset of your browser, you could declare explicitly a date during which daylight saving is not taking effect.

This always returns the summer offset:

```
new Date('August 1, 2000 00:00:00').getTimezoneOffset()
```

This always returns the winter offset:

```
new Date('November 1, 2000 00:00:00').getTimezoneOffset()
```

Comment: How does this give me the fact that I am in Central Standard Time ?

Comment: This answer is based on your first sentence and mostly the title of the question.
You mention that you need to get the browser's time offset at winter time.

this should do exactly that:
new Date('November 1, 2000 00:00:00').getTimezoneOffset() / 60

Comment: But you gave me an Idea to use: new Date('01/01/2000 00:00:00').toTimeString().substr(9) to get the "'GMT-0600 (Central Standard Time)" that il be in the dropdown. So thanks
"

Comment: You are welcome, I updated the answer to be a bit more clear.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are taking this problem from the wrong end.
Javascript allows to give directly the time according to each time zone
the list is here:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones

sample code

```js
const tzUSA = document.getElementById('Times-Zones-USA');

tzUSA.add = (zoneLib,timVal) =>
  {
  let newRow = tzUSA.insertRow()
  newRow.insertCell().textContent = timVal
  newRow.insertCell().textContent = zoneLib
  }

const OptsZ = timZ =>( { hour12:true, timeZone: timZ });  


let nowD = new Date()

tzUSA.add( 'Chicago central (GMT+6)', nowD.toLocaleString('en-US', OptsZ('Etc/GMT+6') ))

tzUSA.add( 'Chicago', nowD.toLocaleString('en-US', OptsZ('America/Chicago') ))
tzUSA.add( 'Denver', nowD.toLocaleString('en-US', OptsZ('America/Denver') ))
tzUSA.add( 'Phoenix', nowD.toLocaleString('en-US', OptsZ('America/Phoenix') ))
tzUSA.add( 'Los Angeles', nowD.toLocaleString('en-US', OptsZ('America/Los_Angeles') ))
tzUSA.add( 'Anchorage', nowD.toLocaleString('en-US', OptsZ('America/Anchorage') ))
tzUSA.add( 'Honolulu', nowD.toLocaleString('en-US', OptsZ('Pacific/Honolulu') ))
```

```css
td { padding: 0.1em .7em;}
td:first-child { text-align: right;}
```

```html
<table id="Times-Zones-USA"></table>
```